# Elasticsearch in Docker: elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError - Python

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch.helpers.scan function to retrieve documents in python. It works fine locally but when running on docker I get the following ConnectionError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from search_results import *
  File "/app/search_results.py", line 9, in <module>
    from BM25_Indexing import *
  File "/app/BM25_Indexing.py", line 13, in <module>
    results = get_data_es() 
  File "/app/Text_Cleaning.py", line 45, in get_data_es
    return list(results_gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 439, in scan
    body=query, scroll=scroll, size=size, request_timeout=request_timeout, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 84, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 1548, in search
    "GET", _make_path(index, doc_type, "_search"), params=params, body=body
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 358, in perform_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 254, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c77b6bd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c77b6bd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

The python code for this error is below:

```
   def get_data_es():
    ES_HOST = {
            "host": "elastic",
            "port": 9200
            }

    ES_INDEX = "radius_ml_posts"
    ES_TYPE = {'author': 'vaibhav'}

    es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[ES_HOST,])
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            es.ping()
            print("Elasticsearch server bounded at url: {}".format(es.cat.master().split()[-2]))
            results_gen = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
                es,
                query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
                index=ES_INDEX
            )
            break
        except elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            time.sleep(5)
            count += 1
            print("Trying to connect to elasticsearch server. Retry number: {}".format(count))
            print("Connections info: {}".format(es.transport.connection_pool.connections))
    return list(results_gen)
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Please help.

EDIT: After employing the solution suggested by @Lupanoide as follows:

```
ES_HOST = os.environ['ES_HOST']
```

And running docker as follows:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e ES_HOST='192.168.1.101:9200' myimage
```

I get the following Connection Timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from search_results import *
  File "/app/search_results.py", line 9, in <module>
    from BM25_Indexing import *
  File "/app/BM25_Indexing.py", line 13, in <module>
    results = get_data_es() 
  File "/app/Text_Cleaning.py", line 44, in get_data_es
    return list(results_gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 439, in scan
    body=query, scroll=scroll, size=size, request_timeout=request_timeout, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 84, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 1548, in search
    "GET", _make_path(index, doc_type, "_search"), params=params, body=body
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 358, in perform_request
    timeout=timeout,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 254, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError((<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd4d21d4ed0>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.101 timed out. (connect timeout=10)')) caused by: ConnectTimeoutError((<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd4d21d4ed0>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.101 timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))
```

Comment: Paste your `docker-compose.yml` or docker command-line you're using, please.

Comment: I dont use the docker compose.

The command line is:
docker run -p 8080:8080 myimage

Comment: What are you running on docker ? The python interpreter or the elasticsearch service ? Because elasticsearch needs port `9200` exposed, not `8080`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the port 9200 is exposed when you run the container.

For example,

If the port is unused in the host system,

```
$ docker run --expose 80 ubuntu bash
```

OR if its already used in the host, use port mapping,

```
$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:8080/tcp ubuntu bash
```

This exposes port 80 of the container without publishing the port to the host system’s interfaces.

Comment: Yes, this is a docker engine command, so runs irrespective of underlying os

Comment: I am getting the same traceback after exposing to 80 using the above mentioned commands.